# Keeping a div the same size no matter the screen resolution

Tags: css, html

Simple question, probably really obvious but, I made a circular div that will be a [floating action button](http://www.google.com/design/spec/components/buttons-floating-action-button.html). I want it to be the same size no matter the screen size or resolution. For example, if it's a half inch wide on a smartphone I want it to also be a half inch wide on an iMac. How can I achieve this?

```css
.fab {
    width: 58px;
    height: 58px;
    position: relative;
    border-radius: 50%;
    background: #F44336;
}
```

```html
<div class="fab"></div>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle?

Comment: Use [absolute lengths](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#absolute-lengths) in the CSS. `.5in` springs to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there are 6 different units in which you can give width height to a element.

**cm** ="centimeters"

**mm**="millimeters"

**in**="inches"

**px**="pixels"

**pt**="points"

**pc**="picas"

here top three **cm**,**mm** and **in** are the units who dose not rely screen resolution etc. use one of these three units instead of **px**

Comment: Sweet! Didn't realize you could use real life units of measurement.

Comment: Note that with the current definitions of CSS, all these units are "real life" units. __pc__ is 1/6 inch, __pt__ is 1/72 inch and __px__ is 1/96 inch. It's just that on low-res screens (such as ordinary desktop monitors), 1 px is rounded to a hardware pixel, and the other units are scaled accordingly. For instance, if your monitor is 110dpi, `1in` still is 96 pixels, or about 0.87 real life inches. With higher resolution devices such as printers, the approximation is better.